# My location get recognized by my SIM card

Tags: root-access, sim-card, geolocation

I noticed that the TikTok app locates me by my SIM card, how is this possible?

I didn't give it any Location/Call/Messages permission. Also, I used VPN but it still recognizes my location.

How can I edit the info on my SIM card? My device is rooted, I got access to everything.

Comment: @Robert the app is tiktok. But what i asked is not about app, i just want to see where the info of simcard saves

Comment: The SIM card does not have any information about it's location. By checking the cell towers and their position you can derive a position. Alternatively the SS7 system running on mobile network provider side may be able to locate you: https://berlin.ccc.de/~tobias/25c3-locating-mobile-phones.pdf